# How to build tensorflow c++ with GPU support without CUDA on windows?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way to build tensorflow c++ or tensorflow lite c++ with GPU support on windows without CUDA, like DirectML or OpenCL. I've heard that some people get cross-build with opencl but I'm not sure whether it's official or not.

My end goal is to get tensorflow.dll or tensorflowlite.dll that runs on the GPU, I prefer DirectML or OpenCL.

I've tried to get a build for DirectML for tensorflow using microsofts tensorflow-directml branch but I think it's a bit out-dated and depricated since it requires tensorflow 1.5 and bazel 0.26 when running configure.py. I'm using tensorflow r2.12 and bazel 5.3. I can downgrade but I'm still unsure about using it.

For tensorflow lite with opencl support, (giving the flag on cmake build), it gives me a visual studio solution, not a dll. I might potentially get a build in visual studio but when I run the solution, after a minute or two of compiling it gives me the following error:

[image: I don't know how to copy-paste on windows error list.]

What are some different ways I can achieve this that's, preferably but not necessarily, official? Are there a way or a technology I'm unaware of that let's me get the build I want?

Comment: What compiler do you use? Seems that it doesn't support latest cpp standards.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Visual Studio 2022 compiler, it's up-to-date. Should I use something else?

Comment: No, but it looks like you didn't set your project to use the latest C++ standard. You didn't provide details how you configure your build, so I can only guess.